# Change text of span with Javascript - without "OnClick"

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I use Squarespace, and have a button on my site that I want the text to change on.

I don't have access to the html, but I can do "javascript::" style stuff with the "button" element. [Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Upv.jpg)

I tried `this.innerhtml`, but it didn't work.

I've also tried:

```
<script>
function changeText(boxID)
{
 document.getElementById($(boxID).attr("id")).innerHTML = 'stuff';
}
</script>
```

and calling `javascript::changeText()`, but that didn't work.

Its a square space site, so I can't change ID name, and they change every time I change anything on the website.
The class names for buttons will select all buttons, so that won't work either.

Update:
This on the button in the little link thing: `javascript:changeText(this);`

This in the code injection panel:

```
<script>
function changeText(box)
{
    var boxID = box.id;
    alert(box.id);
    console.log('element id = ' + id);
    document.getElementById(boxID).innerHTML = 'stuff';
}
</script>
```

I get error `(index):80 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: Updated.

also, no event. The link of the button contained `javascript::changeText();`

Comment: Updated with latest examples of my failings.

Answer (score 1):

At page load you can do like this.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.querySelector('.buttonclassname').innerHTML = 'New text';
    // or an id
    document.querySelector('#buttonid').innerHTML = 'New text';
});
```

*Note, the below ways to find a particular element can of course also be used on page load*

---

***Update 2 based on comments***

At button click there is a few options.

If the button to target isn't unique in any way (and you have access to html), an inline handler can be attached like this

```js
function changeText(elem) {
    elem.innerHTML = 'New text';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeText(this)">Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
```

If you don't have access to the html (and no uniqueness, like an id or class), there might still be uniqueness.

It is always the 3:rd button, do like this

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
if (btn.length > 2) {
  btn[2].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.innerHTML = 'New text';
  });
}
```

```html
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
```

The button contains a know unique text/word

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("button")).forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.innerHTML.indexOf('different') > -1) {
      e.target.innerHTML = 'New text';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text</button>
<button>Old text is different</button>
<button>Old text</button>
```

Comment: Sadly the ID names change without me changing them, and the class name will change all buttons. 

I can call "javascript:: changeText(this);" from the button though, that didn't seem to work.

Comment: But you said you don't have access to the html? ... do you have access to the html, and if, please post it

Comment: Updated with what I tried this round. I think I'm getting closer, but getting "can't set innerHTML of null" errors.

Comment: @NictraSavios Make sure you run that script on load or at the end of the body

Comment: Isn't it only ran once someone actually clicks on the button? I don't have any control over where it is, because I lack html control.

Comment: @NictraSavios Wait a minute, is it when someone clicks on the button?

Comment: Since I can edit the "href" of the button and nothing else, I set the href to `javascript::changeText(this);`

Comment: @NictraSavios Added a 2:nd sample to my answer

Comment: Like I said, I can't edit the html (I can't add an Onlick) with squarespace.

I have a button block which contains text and an href, and I have a code injection panel that puts things into the header.

That's all I have, so OnClick Does not work

Comment: @NictraSavios Ok, did yet another update .. will that work for you?

Comment: @LGSon Wouldn't that make it so that any button on the website, when pressed, would change?

What is incorrect with my approach of javascript calls via href? My only issue so far is that the ID passed by "this" seems to be the wrong ID.

Comment: @NictraSavios It will, so you can either change the `querySelectorAll` to target buttons which has a specific class name, like `.blue-buttons` or add an if statement like `if (e.target.className == 'blue-buttons') { ... }` ... that is entirely up to you ... so if you tell me what's unique I'll update my answer for you

Comment: @NictraSavios Did my answer help you?

Comment: Sadly no, since all squarespace buttons have the same class, and I can't change them.

Comment: @NictraSavios Can you tell in what way the one's you want to target differs? .. Other than class name, for example attributes, or inner structure of child elements

Comment: None.

Same class, same attributes same structure as all other buttons, only the text changes. 

This is why I used href="javascript::" and still think its the best solution.

Comment: @NictraSavios Updated my answer with some other approaches.